# On Windows 10 (1803), all applications lost touch or stylus if a WPF transparent window covers on them

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

If I create a new WPF application with a simple empty window like the code shown below, I find that all applications which are covered by the WPF app lost touch or stylus reaction. This can only be reproduced when Windows 10 is upgraded to 1803 (10.0.17134.0).

```
<Window x:Class="TheWPFCoveringWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
        Topmost="True">
    <Button Content="Test" Width="200" Height="100" />
</Window>
```

I wrote another WPF application to find out what happened. So I add a StylusDown event to the Window like the code shown below:

```
// This code is in another WPF application.
private void OnStylusDown(object sender, StylusDownEventArgs e)
{
    // Set a breakpoint here.
}
```

But the breakpoint never reached until I closed the transparent WPF window which is on top.

I pushed the very simple code to GitHub: [dotnet-campus/TouchIssueOnWindows10.0.17134](https://github.com/dotnet-campus/TouchIssueOnWindows10.0.17134). Cloning it might help a little.

Why does this happen and how to solve it? Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: I try to set the TouchIssueOnWindows to 4.7 and support pointer but I find it cant use Pointer message in another application.

Comment: I found I cant touch any UWP, like edge and twitter, until I closed the TouchIssueOnWindows

Comment: How about setting `Background="{x:Null}"`?

Comment: @Iron It still reproduces even if the background is null.

Comment: May be the window is eating your events. Try diabling the hittest on the window.

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota Thanks! But actually, I've tried your solution by adding `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on my `Window` and other controls. It still reproduces.

Comment: Have you tried setting Focusable to true on your window?

Comment: @AvdotiyFedorov You mean the covering WPF window or the windows that are covered behind? It helps nothing by setting the covering window focusable. And we can't access the code of those variety windows behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated

Microsoft has fixed this issue in **[.NET Framework August 2018 Preview of Quality Rollup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/08/30/net-framework-august-2018-preview-of-quality-rollup/)**.

- [August 30, 2018—KB4346783 (OS Build 17134.254)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4346783/windows-10-update-kb4346783)

> Addresses an issue where touch and mouse events were handled differently in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications that have a transparent overlay window.

---

#### Original

After a whole week's debugging, I finally find out the solution.

Just add a `ResizeMode="NoResize"` property for the Window as the code shown below:

```
<Window x:Class="TheWPFCoveringWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized"
        AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="Transparent" Topmost="True">
    <Button Content="Test" Width="200" Height="100" />
</Window>
```

@lindexi has posted this issue and this solution into his post. If you want more information about this issue, read [win10 17025 touch bug - lindexi](https://lindexi.github.io/lindexi/post/win10-17025-%E8%A7%A6%E6%91%B8bug.html) for more details. (This post is written in multiple languages, so you'll miss nothing even if you ignore the unknown characters.)

Actually, I still can't figure out why this property helps.

Could anyone explain the reason for this issue?

Comment: I post to [On Windows 10 (1803), all applications lost touch or stylus if a WPF transparent window covers on them - Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/255063/on-windows-10-1803-all-applications-lost-touch-or.html )