# Combo Box touch events not firing in Windows 10 VS2017

Tags: wpf, combobox, visual-studio-2017, touch

Created a test application with a  wpf combo box.
Using  touch select an  item from Combo box,after selecting the item combo box  close after a flickering.
This  flickering is not observed using mouse clicks.
Following are the specification for Application:
1.Made AllowsTransparency="True" for windows
2.Unchecked "Enable press and hold for right clicking" in Pen and Touch setting
System Specification:
1.Windows 10
2.VS 2017 and .Net framework 4.7
Some search results shows it is a common issue in Windows 10 that when windows is transparent touch events are not firing.
[On Windows 10 (1803), all applications lost touch or stylus if a WPF transparent window covers on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382605/on-windows-10-1803-all-applications-lost-touch-or-stylus-if-a-wpf-transparent)
Workaround mentioned  in it is not working in our case.(ResizeMode="NoResize") .
Is there any other workaround for this?
Following is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="cb" Height="50" Width="50">
            <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>C</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>D</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>E</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>F</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>G</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalOnly"

Comment: I've followed your description and got the same issue. I'm having a try to fix it.

Comment: @lindexi I've tried your recommendation, it's a bit ridiculous and not work, just as I have predicted.

Comment: I've tested many properties and debug the .NET Framework code via dnSpy, but I temporarily got a few useful info.

Comment: @walterlv could you please share the info.Is this issue of the .Net frame work?

Comment: @Krish Yes, it's definitely the .NET Framework bug. but we may have some solutions to avoid it. You can view my questions, I have another question and post talking about WPF touch bugs.

Comment: @walterlv One of the Workaround mentioned in it is not working in our caseas I mentioned in my Question(ResizeMode="NoResize").Could you please share link of other solutions?

Comment: Microsoft addresses an issue where "touch and mouse events were handled differently in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications that have a transparent overlay window" in [KB4346783](https://support.microsoft.com/zh-cn/help/4346783/windows-10-update-kb4346783) release. But the above @Krish reported behavior is still there even if kb4346783 is updated.

Comment: I bring to https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3040